# Convert passwords in a Laravel user list to use in a non-laravel PHP program

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the MySQL database from an App written using Laravel. I need to use that database's users table to work in another, non-Laravel program.

The passwords are in the format $2y$10$2FNabPaVA30hPhMwrO4CgexrFcrJyYXM/oQEmRXTo3NpFmSLhh7QO

This does not appear to be MD5 or any other standard hash.

Is there a formula that I can apply to the incoming passwords to match the Laravel password hash.

Comment: Oiy Coder! Tron from VIP we need help. Can you give server manager rights to Sailor?

Answer (score 1):

In their documentation their default password hashing algorithm is Bcrypt.
It’s a standard algorithm in the PHP standard library. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/hashing Here is the doc for laravel.
And here is the doc for the php function for hashing the password: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Now! To verify a hash in the database against a provided non-hashed password. You Can use password_verify(). It returns a boolean.
Here is an example.

If(password_verify(‘password’, $hashedpasswordfromdatabase)
echo ‘valid’;
else
echo ‘invalid’;

The doc for password_verify is here: http://php.net/password_verify

Edit:
Very important though! If you hash the same password, you Will end up with two different hashes. That is because the algorithm uses a different salt. That is why password_verify is used. It Can extract the salt of the hashed password and use that salt on a non-hashed password and then compare them.